# SQL "specified data type is not valid" error

Tags: sql

Why does SQL server express 2008 give me this error?

```
CREATE TABLE model (
name varchar(3),
desc varchar(25)
)


0x80040E14, Minor Error 26302
> CREATE TABLE model (
name varchar(3),
desc varchar(25)
)
The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = varchar ]
```

Comment: Please choose question titles that describe what your question is generally about. "Newbie question" could be pretty much anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `DESC` is a SQL keyword.  You can either use a different column name (say, `description`) or put brackets around `desc`:

```
[desc] VARCHAR(25)
```

Answer (score 6):

SqlCe is a Unicode-only database so you need nvarchar instead of varchar.

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is a reserved SQL keyword. In SQL Server, you can escape reserved name by surround the name with [], like `[desc]`.

Or, don't use abbreviation and name your column `Description`.

Answer (score 0):

Both repsonses I've seen are correct.

DESC is short for DESCENDING (as in the ORDER BY clause) and so is reserved.  Using 'desc' or [desc] will avoid that problem and allow field names with spaces, etc, as well.

(Note: I don't recommend using keywords as field names or aliases.  Nor do I recommend putting spaces in them.  but with '' or [] you Can...)